# How to set a job to manual based on previous stage failure in gitlab pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-auto-devops

I have a pipeline as below.

If I keep the allow_failure value true for the teardown job, the next job is running directly.

[allow_failure=true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHtr4.png)

If I keep the allow_failure value false for the teardown job, the next job is set in a state of skip, and I can’t run it manually later.

[allow_failure=false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvCNQ.png)

The play button now doesn’t work for my last job.

How to set it in such a way, when the teardown job fails, we can come and run it manually the next job(destroy-admin-server) later.

Please suggest.